# Writing Eloquent version of query with Not Where condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I write this query in eloquent?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table`
WHERE 
    !(
        ((col0 = 'AA') AND (col1 = 'AA'))
     OR
        ((col0 = 'BB') AND (col1 = 'BB'))
    )
```

This is the Eloquent version I have:

```
        $query->where(function ($sub_query){
            $sub_query->orWhere(function ($sub_sub_query){
                $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                    // Some stuff
                });
                $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                    // Some stuff
                });
            });
            $sub_query->orWhere(function ($sub_sub_query){
                $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                    // Some stuff
                });
                $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                    // Some stuff
                });
            });
        });
```

I haven't found anything to do WHERE !(XXX)

Thanks!

EDIT:

I found the solution:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/negate-entire-nested-where-clause

There is the code:

```
        $query->where(function ($sub_query){
            $sub_query->orWhere(function ($sub_sub_query){
                $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                    // Some stuff
                });
                $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                    // Some stuff
                });
            });
            $sub_query->orWhere(function ($sub_sub_query){
                $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                    // Some stuff
                });
                $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                    // Some stuff
                });
            });
        }, null, null, 'AND NOT');
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/negate-entire-nested-where-clause

There is the code:

```
    $query->where(function ($sub_query){
        $sub_query->orWhere(function ($sub_sub_query){
            $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                // Some stuff
            });
            $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                // Some stuff
            });
        });
        $sub_query->orWhere(function ($sub_sub_query){
            $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                // Some stuff
            });
            $sub_sub_query->where(function ($sub_sub_query){
                // Some stuff
            });
        });
    }, null, null, 'AND NOT');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `query` change in `Model` for your `table model` check this and `test`

```
$object = Model::where([['col0' ,'<>', 'AA'],['col1','<>','AA']])
->orWhere([['col0','<>','BB'],['col1','<>', 'BB']])->get();
```

Comment: I need to add the question mark before the brackets: WHERE !(# SOME STUFF #)

Comment: you need result diferent at AA and BB??

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your query into something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table`
WHERE 
    (
        ((col0 != 'AA') OR (col1 != 'AA'))
     AND
        ((col0 != 'BB') OR (col1 != 'BB'))
    )
```

Which gives the same result, and can be expressed with this :

```
    $query->where(function ($sub_query){
        $sub_query->Where(function ($sub_sub_query){
            $sub_sub_query->where('col0' ,'!=', 'AA')
                          ->Orwhere('col1' ,'!=', 'AA');
        });
        $sub_query->Where(function ($sub_sub_query){
            $sub_sub_query->where('col0' ,'!=', 'BB')
                          ->Orwhere('col1' ,'!=', 'BB');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
!(
    ((col0 = 'AA') AND (col1 = 'AA'))
  OR
    ((col0 = 'BB') AND (col1 = 'BB'))
)
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE
    !((col0 = 'AA') AND (col1 = 'AA')) 
  AND
    !((col0 = 'BB') AND (col1 = 'BB'))
```

since NOT ( A OR B ) === NOT A AND NOT B

**simplifying more** it becomes

```
WHERE
    ( !(col0 = 'AA') OR !(col1 = 'AA') )  
  AND
    ( !(col0 = 'BB') OR !(col1 = 'BB') )
```

since NOT A and B === NOT A OR NOT B

so the query can be built like this..

```
$q->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('col0','!=','AA')->orWhere('col1','!=','AA');
})->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('col0','!=','BB')->orWhere('col1','!=','BB');
});
```